# JQM changepage function causes phonegap app to freeze and disables internal links

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am encountering a new and strange error regarding the JQM function $.mobile.changePage(). I have several listviews throughout my app but when I added the latest one to the homepage of the app I find that this function is causing all other internal links to stop working and the function never actually changes the page. It appears to freeze.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){       
    $('#top-gender-list').on('click', 'li', function(data){ 
        currentBar.id = $(this).attr('id');
        currentBar.name = $(this).text();

        $.mobile.changePage("#bar");    ///freezes here  FYI data is being returned successfully
    });
});
```

// Here is a function that HAS worked in the past before the one above was added. Now it no longer works. It is doing the same thing as the one above. (Stops all internal links from working and never changes pages)

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#bars', function(){       
    $('#bars').on('click', 'li', function(data){
        currentBar.id = $(this).attr('id');
        currentBar.name = $(this).text();       
        $.mobile.changePage("#bar");        
    });
});
```

I cannot figure out if this is due to a syntax error or a glitch with phonegap.

FYI none of these problems occur when I upload this code to a webserver. All listitem links work perfectly.